# How to obtain a persistent login when using a CasperJS login script?

Tags: webserver, phantomjs, load-testing, casperjs

I have a CasperJS script which logs into our test website platform.  Our website application produces dynamic data which is updated every second, and normally using a web browser the login is left running (as you would using webmail)

The script logs into the website as a user, waits five seconds for the page to populate with data and uses the this.capture function to grab a screen shot to confirm the details are correct.

What I want to do, is follow on from the login as I've noticed the CasperJS script does not stay logged in as our customers logins are persistent.

I want to do this because we are load testing a new proof of concept platform.

Does anyone know how I make CasperJS do this?

I also want to parse a csv list of username/passwords to simulate logins - I'm presuming that I have to do this via a shell script or get PhantomJS invoke each login sequentially?

(background:  I'm not a web developer, but someone with 20 years of IT and Unix/Infrastructure - so I would class myself as an intermediate skill scripting)

Answer (score 3):

#### Persistent login

This is what the [`--cookies-file`](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) commandline option is for. It stores all cookies in a file on disk and on subsequent invocations of the script will use the stored cookies to restore the session. So just run your script like this:

```
casperjs --cooies-file=cookies.txt yourScript.js
```

yourScript.js should be able to tell that are already logged in.

#### Multiple credentials

Your other problem can be solved in different ways, but none of them should be invoked with the `--cookies-file` option.

1. Since a CSV is a simple file format you can read it through the PhantomJS `fs` module and iterate over them with `casper.eachThen`. For each iteration, you would need to login, do your thing and don't forget to log *out* just in the same way you would do in a browser session.
2. Parse the CSV somehow in the shell and pass the pairs into CasperJS. Then you can access `casper.cli` to get the credentials to log in. With this option you don't need to log out, since each invocation runs in its own PhantomJS instance and doesn't share cookies.

   This option can be combined with your first question, if that is what you want. Add on each invocation the option `--cookies-file=cookies_<username>.txt`, so you can run the shell script multiple times without logging in each time.

#### Load testing

If I understood correctly, then the web application is password protected. You would need to run a separate CasperJS process for each username/password pair. You should check the memory footprint for one script invocation and scale up. Memory is the primary limiting factor which you can calculate for your test machine, but CPU will also hit a limit somewhere.

PhantomJS/CasperJS instances are full browsers and are therefore much heavier than a slim webserver. So you will probably need multiple machines each with many instances that run your script to load test the webserver.